# how to implement longClickListen on RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onitemlongclicklistener

After searching for a solution for hours, I could implement ItemClickListener but for some reason, I cannot use the same method to implement itomLongClickListener. it gives me "Type Mismatch" error: ****Type mismatch.
Required:Boolean
Found:Unit****

I would really appreciate if you could pinpoint what I am doing wrong.

Below is my code

```
class MyAdapter(ct: Context, s1: Array<String>, s2: Array<String>?):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    var nameList: Array<String>? = null
    var oneLineMessage: Array<String>? = null
    var context: Context? = null

    init {
        nameList = s1
        oneLineMessage = s2
        context = ct

    }

    fun onClick(view :View){
        val intent= Intent(context,SecondPage::class.java)
        context?.startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        var v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.friendName?.text = nameList?.get(position)
        if (oneLineMessage != null) {
            holder.messagePreview?.text = oneLineMessage?.get(position)
        } else {
            holder.messagePreview?.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        holder.layout?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val intent= Intent(context,SecondPage::class.java)
            context?.startActivity(intent)
        })
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return nameList?.size as Int
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var friendName: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameText)
        var messagePreview: TextView? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messagePreview)
        var layout: RelativeLayout? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondPageConstraintLayout)

        init {
            
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                val position=adapterPosition+1
                Toast.makeText(context, "you chose $position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener {
                val position=adapterPosition+1
                Toast.makeText(context, "you long pressed $position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  })
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`View.OnLongClickListner` is an Interface with `boolean onLongClick(View v)`, that's mean you must return `boolean`.

return true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise.

`show()` returns `Unit` and that's your last line in your lambda `{}`

so if you consumed the long click on your `itemView` just return `true`

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
    val position=adapterPosition+1
    Toast.makeText(context, "you long pressed $position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    true
}
```